# This version of the application is not configured for billing after app update

Tags: java, android, eclipse, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am not sure what im doing wrong here so please help if you can. 
I have an app with in app billing. The app was working correctly and in app billing was also up and running. meaning i had a few friends download it from google play store and make a purchase and it worked perfectly.

I made some minor bug fixes to the apps layout (it was crashing on some tablets) then changed the android version code and android version code name. uploaded the new apk. after that the in app billing is no longer working and giving the error posted on the main title

New published not working apk info:
3 (1.0.1) Aug 27, 2014  in Prod

Old working apk info : 
2 (1.0) Aug 14, 2014 Unpublished

I have a feeling there is something i did wrong regarding the version codes or something and im not able to figure it out so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Also since i did some research and it was stated that it might take some time for google servers to update i waited a little over 24hrs to ask for help, just to make sure.

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out yesterday and wanted to share the answer here in case someone has the same issue. 
What i to get it to work. 
I exported (signed) a new apk with android version code (it was 3 so i gave it a 4)
BUT the most important part was that i changed the version code name back to 1.0 (this was the original version code name before i did an update to version code name 1.0.1 and my in app billing stopped working)

Another thing i did was that i first uploaded the new apk to the alpha channel on google play, then manually installed that same apk i uploaded to google on my device and kept checking to see when it would work properly. In a few hours the in app billing started to work so i moved the apk from alpha channel to production on google play and now everything is fine.

I dont know which one of those did the trick , the part where i changed the version code name back to 1.0 or the fact that i uploaded the signed apk first to the alpha channel but in any case it worked for me so i hope this helps someone else.